# Mutating a dictionary using a def in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary ('wakeup' in the code below) in which the values are lists.

I would like to change the second element of each list using a def, just like below:

```
def auto(t):
    wakeup('zone1')[1] = wakeup('zone1')[0] - t

wakeup = {'zone1': [15, auto(1)],
          'zone2': [15, auto(1)]}

print wakeup
```

It will not work because auto() makes a reference to wakeup before wakeup having been defined.

Yet if I try to fix this by having the def AFTER the wakeup definition, then I would still be getting an error since this time the wakeup dictionary would be making a reference to auto() before auto() having been defined.

Ideally I would like to keep this syntax in the lists: [15, auto(1)]

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling function `auto` in the declaration of variable `wakeup`, and you are attempting to use variable `wakeup` inside function `auto`.

So you are essentially attempting to use variable `wakeup` before it has been instantiated.

First, you need to decide what initial values you want for variable `wakeup`:

```
wakeup = {'zone1': [15, zone1_def_val],
          'zone2': [15, zone2_def_val]}
```

Then, you can call function `auto` whenever needed:

```
def auto(t):
    wakeup['zone1'][1] = wakeup['zone1'][0] - t

auto(2)
auto(3)
auto(5)
...
print wakeup
```

Please note that you need to use `[]` and not `()` when accessing an element in a dictionary:

```
wakeup['zone1'] # good
wakeup('zone1') # bad
```

Comment: I have one tiny objection which is that he is not actually changing the global variable but the instance of the dictionary pointed by that variable(which is a reference): he is not reassigning it. It will work without global. I still think one should always use it when dealing with a global variable.

Comment: @Samy Arous: Hmmmm, are you sure? looks to me function `auto` changes a global variable here... I'll give it a try...

Comment: Yes I am, in python 2.7 at least. I'm not yet used to python 3. If he were to assign a new value to wakeup: wakupe = {'zone1': [5, 0]} then global would be necessary there.

Comment: @Samy Arous: Yep, you're right! Thanks for the correction, answer revised (removed `global wakeup` from function `auto`).

Comment: Thanks a lot people for helping me out! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`auto` really has nothing to do with the dictionary, and you should define it that way.

```
def auto(n, t):
    return n - t

wakeup = {'zone1': [15, auto(15, 1)], 'zone2': [15, auto(15, 1)]}
```

But if your actual code is similar to this, then you don't really need a function at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was this simple after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is simply not valid.

The best way to modify a dictionary inside a function is to pass it as an argument

```
def auto(d, t):
    for l in d.values():
        l[1] = l[0] - t

wakeup = {'zone1': [15, 0],
          'zone2': [15, 0]}

auto(wakeup, 1)
```

if you still want to modify the dictionary but don't want to pass it as an argument, use the global syntax

```
def auto(t):
    global wakeup
    for l in wakeup.values():
        l[1] = l[0] - t

wakeup = {'zone1': [15, 0],
          'zone2': [15, 0]}

auto(1)
```

In this particular case, and since you are not reassigning wakeup, you don't really need global but it's better to always use it, just as it's also better to avoid as much as possible using global variables.

This code is valid:

```
def auto(t):

    for l in wakeup.values():
        l[1] = l[0] - t

wakeup = {'zone1': [15, 0],
          'zone2': [15, 0]}

auto(1)
```